# Database is full in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I tried to write delete query in sqlite database:
DELETE FROM photoGalleryTbl WHERE id=204
and I got error:
"Error: **database is full**".

Can I remove that record? How??

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you get this figured out? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the partition where the sqlite file is stored is full; try to move the file elsewhere and retry the delete command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try to move the DB file to some other location and try to use delete command and also check if you have stored the data in DB

Answer (score 0):

It probably is the drive or the partition. Might even be that the drive or the DB file is read-only.
Alternatively, you could try querying the following database properties to find out why the DB is reporting that it is full:

`max_page_count`

`page_count`

`journal_size_limit`